# Отслеживание вызова функций C#

Tags: c#

При вызове функций необходимо выполнять запись в базу действия. Функции все разнородные, т.е. различаются входные и выходные параметры, поэтому я не смог решить эту задачу через делегаты, хотя я возможно чего-то не понимаю.
Метод, записывающий в базу будет один:

```
public void AddAction(int idAction, int index)
        {
            using (DataBaseContext db = new DataBaseContext())
            {
                var sa = new StudentAction
                {
                    reportCard = db.ReportCards.First(item => item.ID == StudentID),
                    Act = db.DictActs.First(item => item.ID == idAction),
                    IndexAct = index,
                    CorrectExecution = true
                };
                db.StudentActions.Add(sa);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Мне необходимо вызывать этот метод и передавать свои параметры при каждом вызове заданных функций.
Прошу дать хотя бы направление: какую тему и в какую сторону изучать.

Comment: DispatchProxy/PostSharp/Interceptions или в общем: Аспектно-ориентированное программирование

Comment: Благодарю. Попробую разобраться.

Comment: Если это всего пара методов - то проще руками в низ добавить код. Если это пара классов - то проще накатать декоаторы доя них. Если вы используете DI/IoC контейнеры, во многих из них уже есть встроенные перехватчики. Если все, что я перечислил, не подходит вам, то тогда смотрите на AOP, из первого комментария, но это как крайний случай, это уже тяжелая артиллерия со своими последстивиями.

Comment: Методов более двух сотен. Ручками забивать долго и геморно. Нашёл реализацию через оболочку Method((Action<dynamic>)Method).